# Sales Order reports Missing data

Tags: magento2, sales-order, reports

Sales data missing from order reports but sales appear in the order grid

Magento ver. 2.1.9

we have some days they are showing some days and some that are show all the correct orders but some show nothing at at all.

Comment: check magento logs

Comment: aggregated data was causing issue so untill i can resolve this reports are working will have to do with out the dashboard

Comment: This is still happening to me in 2.3.4-p3 and nothing i try fixes it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial resolution but i now have by setting use aggregated data to yes

if any body has same issue please go configuration/sales/sales/dashboard and set aggregated data to yes